# How to protect images from other applications in android?

Tags: android, image-gallery

In my application am downloading lot of images from web in order to use them in my application. But problem is that android creating thumbnails for all my images (Gallery).

Is there any way to protect my images so other applications like gallery can not access them?

Answer (score 1):

Make your folder hidden in SD card by naming your folder starts with "." (.foldername).

This will hide your folder accessing from other android applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the images from the Gallery, just add an empty file called [`.nomedia`](http://androinica.com/2009/08/28/how-to-hide-non-music-audio-files-from-appearing-in-android-media-players/) in the folder where you are downloading them and the `MediaScanner` will skip that folder.

However, this will not prevent nosy apps that explicitly go and look in that folder searching for other apps pictures.

I don't know of a way to lock down access to files on the SD card for specific application only. You could try writing the picture in a `FileOutputStream` created using [`Context.openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29); however, as far as I know, the file permissions are not really enforced by the OS on the SD card. Give it a try, it might work though.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the documentation says that if you download the files to the SD card, they are public.  So even though you're app gets it's own little folder, that data is considered to be public, and thus if you want to keep it private, you must encrypt it.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to encrypt files and folder in sdcard ? How to access in my application ?

Comment: @Srinivas: Did you get to encrypt your application images and access them in you app? Can you share the details of how to do it?